# How to return value from child function to parent function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, arangodb

I want a value from child function to the parent function in a `Node.js` and use that value in another file. Being asynchronous flow the output of `d.promise` is pending.
How can I get the value of `d.promise` as fulfilled with the data passed in the `arangoFunction.js` file in the `queryCheck` variable in the `site.js` file?

Database used : ArangoDB

**site.js snippet**

```
var arangoFunc = require('./arangoFunction'), queryCheck;
queryCheck = arangoFunc.saveData(data, roleCollection, res);
console.log(queryCheck);
```

**arangoFunction.js snippet**

```
var q = require('q');
var d = q.defer();
    exports.saveData = function(data, collectionName, res){
          var collectionData = db.collection(collectionName);
          collectionData.save(data, function(e, o){
              if(e) {
                console.error(e);
                res.status(e.response.statusCode).send(e.response.statusMessage);
                d.reject(false);
              }
              else {
                res.send(data);
                d.resolve(data);
              }
            });
            return d.promise;
        }
```

**Output of site.js snippet**

```
{ state: 'pending' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**arangoFunction.js**

```
exports.saveData = function(data, collectionName, res){
  var collectionData = db.collection(collectionName);
  return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify){
    collectionData.save(data, function(e, o){
      if(e) {
        console.error(e.response.statusMessage);
        res.status(e.response.statusCode).send(e.response.statusMessage);
        reject(e);
      }
      else {
        res.send(data);
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

**site.js**

```
arangoFunc.saveData(data, roleCollection, res).then(function(value){
 // do whatever with the returned data
}, function(err){
 // error handling
});
```